# Deploying Grails 3 App throws FlashScope Exception

Tags: grails, flash-scope, grails3

When deploying a new version of a Grails 3.1.1 application war into a running Tomcat, I am presented with an exception when accessing it after deployment.

```
Oct 13, 2016 11:39:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [/acses] threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.grails.web.servlet.GrailsFlashScope cannot be cast to grails.web.mvc.FlashScope
        at org.grails.web.servlet.DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes.getFlashScope(DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes.java:173)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:188)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:171)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:135)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:333)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:193)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It only happens roughly once in three or four deployments and so far and a restart of Tomcat fixes it (i.e. the error does not happen on Tomcat start), I've not been able to come up with what's causing it. It is also happening on another Grails application that a colleague is writing.

**Update:** It's now happening more frequently, hence the bounty.

The application does not make use of flash to pass messages. The session is being used but I've ensured that all objects stored there are thread-safe.

Happy to provide any other additional information upon request, as I'm not sure what is needed to troubleshoot this one.

**Update 2:** I couldn't find any classpath clashes, however, I'll post my dependency list just in case someone else spots something:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.1"
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    provided "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3" // oracle jdbc driver provided by tomcat
    compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:5.0.0.RELEASE" // REST client
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache:3.0.2" // cache plugin
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar') // libs directory contains openldap jar.
    provided "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:9.0.0.M1"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}
```

**Update 3:** Dependency report as requested: [here](http://pastebin.com/6PMy30xT).

Comment: most probably a classloader issue - make sure you dont have 2 jars file with the class `grails.web.mvc.FlashScope`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri thanks, I'll check that but I doubt that's the issue. If it were a classloader issue, it would happen on every load of Tomcat. This only occurs when I deploy a new version of the war file while Tomcat is running. Restarting Tomcat fixes it.

Comment: you'll better provide the dependencies report from gradle

Comment: @FrédéricHenri done. See link in question.